# Drawing a path which realises the diameter of the graph

Tags: graphs-and-networks

So I enter a (0,1) adjacency matrix and I get the following graph:

[image]

The diameter of this graph is 4. How can I ask that two vertices which realise
this diameter be drawn with different filling colour, say a, and the edges on the path of length 4 between them be drawn with color b?

Comment: You may have multiple instances of pairs realising the max distance

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
g = ExampleData[{"NetworkGraph", "ZacharyKarateClub"}]

dm = GraphDistanceMatrix[g];

Position[dm, Max[dm]]
(* {{15, 20}, {15, 24}, {15, 25}, {15, 29}, {15, 30}, {15, 
  31}, {15, 32}, {15, 33}, {20, 15}, {24, 15}, {25, 15}, {29, 
  15}, {30, 15}, {31, 15}, {32, 15}, {33, 15}} *)

pair = VertexList[g][[#]] & /@ First[%]
(* {17, 24} *)

path = FindShortestPath[g, Sequence @@ pair]
(* {17, 6, 1, 3, 28, 24} *)

HighlightGraph[g, {Style[pair, Yellow], 
  Style[UndirectedEdge @@@ Partition[path, 2, 1], Red]}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

---

[The IGraph/M package](http://szhorvat.net/mathematica/IGraphM) has a fast function for this that avoids keeping the entire distance matrix in memory. I recommend it for large graphs.

```
<< IGraphM`
```

> IGraph/M 0.3.91 (May 5, 2017)
>   Evaluate IGDocumentation[] to get started.

```
?IGFindDiameter
```

> `IGFindDiameter[graph]` returns a longest shortest path in graph, i.e. a shortest path with length equal to the graph diameter. Available `Method` options: `{"Unweighted", "Dijkstra"}`.

```
HighlightGraph[g, PathGraph@IGFindDiameter[g]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: If you have questions, comment on this answer.

Comment: I had another answer using `GraphPeriphery`, but it turns out this one is faster.

Comment: Hm, looks like this one is actually much faster for dense graphs, but slower for sparse graphs.  I'll go ahead and post mine then.

Comment: Beautiful, thanks!

Comment: Just a question: would it be possible to draw the coloured line slightly thicker than the rest?

Comment: Yes, use `Directive[Red,Thick]`.  Pretty much all of your regular graphics options apply (see the doc for `Style`).

Comment: By the way, does anyone know how to get matching colours? For instance I have used blue!50!white and 
red!50!white in other parts of my .tex file and I'd like
to have the same here as well.

Answer (score 9):

Assuming your graph is `g`:

```
p = GraphPeriphery[g];
s = First[p];
d = GraphDiameter[g];
t = First@Select[Rest[p], GraphDistance[g, s, #] == d &, 1]
```

The vertices returned by `GraphPeriphery` will be maximally distant from at least one other vertex in the graph (and that vertex will also be in `GraphPeriphery`).  Select one at random (the `First` one works fine) and compare its distance with each other vertex in `p` to the diameter, stopping at the first one.  From here you can style exactly like Szabolcs did, except replace `pair` with `{s, t}`.  Something like this:

```
HighlightGraph[g, {Style[PathGraph@FindShortestPath[g, s, t], Green], 
  Style[{s, t}, Red]}]
```

[image]

Szabolcs solution is very slightly faster for dense graphs, and this solution is faster for sparse graphs.

Comment: @the_fox My answer is not as clean/straightforward as Szabolcs anyway.  I'd only suggest using mine if you run into performance issues on large graphs.